# JFrame background not changing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, background-color

I've got a simple program to change the background of a JFrame and the foreground of a JLabel.  The JFrame has a JLabel and 2 JButtons on it, one to change the words and the other to change the background.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ColorChooserDemo extends JPanel {

static JFrame frame;
JLabel label;
JButton button1, button2;

public ColorChooserDemo() {
    this.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 255));
    setLayout(null);

    label = new JLabel("This is Text");
    button1 = new JButton("Set Word Color");
    button2 = new JButton("Set Background Color");

    add(label);
    add(button1);
    add(button2);

    label.setBounds(130, 10, 111, 15);
    button1.setBounds(100, 40, 200, 35);
    button2.setBounds(70, 90, 250, 35);

    button1.addActionListener(buttonPressed);
    button2.addActionListener(buttonPressed);
    button1.setActionCommand("words");
    button2.setActionCommand("back");

    label.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 20));
    button1.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 20));
    button2.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 20));
}

AbstractAction buttonPressed = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("words")) {
            Color c = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Choose a Color", label.getForeground());
            if (c != null)
                label.setForeground(c);
        }
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("back")) {
            Color c = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Choose a Color", label.getForeground());
            if (c != null)
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(c);
        }
        repaint();
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    frame = new JFrame("ColorChooserDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new ColorChooserDemo());
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setLocation((int) (screenSize.getWidth() - 400) / 2, (int) (screenSize.getHeight() - 200) / 2);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

For whatever reason`frame.getContentPane().setBackground(c);` doesn't work.
I've looked for solutions but nothing is working and I don't understand why.  Please help.

--EDIT--
I tried `repaint();` and it still doesn't work.  Could it have to do with `frame` being static?

Comment: The label color does change, but not the JFrame?

Comment: Try repainting the content pane after changing colors with repaint()

Comment: There are lots of reasons this might not work, but without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it would all be vauge guess work on our part

Comment: @Knox From memory, `setBackground` is a bound method, meaning it generates it's own `repaint` call

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added the rest of the code.  I thought about putting the whole thing up originally, but I figured you might be able to help just from the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of where something like `static` can stab you in the back...

So, in your code, you are doing...

```
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(c);
```

when you want to change the background color, but you have to ask yourself the question, what is the `contentPane`?  Since your component extends from `JPanel` (which is opaque) and sets it's own background color (`this.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 255));`) (and because by default `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout`) you component is covering the entire content area of the frame, so any calls to `frame.getContentPane().setBackground(c)` are simply not visible (because your panel is covering it).

Instead, you should simple use...

```
setBackground(c);
```

For clarification...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ColorChooserDemo extends JPanel {

    JLabel label;
    JButton button1, button2;

    public ColorChooserDemo() {
        this.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 255));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        label = new JLabel("This is Text");
        button1 = new JButton("Set Word Color");
        button2 = new JButton("Set Background Color");

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        add(label, gbc);
        add(button1, gbc);
        add(button2, gbc);

        button1.addActionListener(buttonPressed);
        button2.addActionListener(buttonPressed);
        button1.setActionCommand("words");
        button2.setActionCommand("back");

        label.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 20));
        button1.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 20));
        button2.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 20));
    }

    AbstractAction buttonPressed = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("words")) {
                Color c = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Choose a Color", label.getForeground());
                if (c != null) {
                    label.setForeground(c);
                }
            }
            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("back")) {
                System.out.println("...");
                Color c = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Choose a Color", getBackground());
                if (c != null) {
                    setBackground(c);
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ColorChooserDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new ColorChooserDemo());
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setLocation((int) (screenSize.getWidth() - 400) / 2, (int) (screenSize.getHeight() - 200) / 2);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I would also strongly suggest you have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) and [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more details about how the layou management API works